# Bake per vertex color to Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, vertex-colors

So, I was trying to make the colours of a obj created by this Demo make by the talented people of the Computer Vision Laboratory of University of Nottingham and with no success and frustration I wasn't able to make the colours show up, even less bake to a normal texture map.

Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzYWU.png

Link for you to try be yourself http://cvl-demos.cs.nott.ac.uk/vrn/

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: What is your question, could you elaborate? Also add some more info to your post like screenshots and details about the issue. Don't rely on people downloading a file to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry for not clearing my question My issue is view and bake the vertex color of this mesh https://i.imgur.com/IEN8rkm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that .OBJ format by standard does not support vertex colors, so Blender isn't importing them. The way to append vertex color after vertex position is only a third-party hack to the format, and thus the support is limited in many applications.

Please follow this post about importing an .OBJ file with vertex colors into Blender and you should be able to see, render and bake the colors no problem.

[How to display and use Vertex Color from OBJ model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90890/how-to-display-and-use-vertex-color-from-obj-model)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way Blender handles vertex colors. if I import the mesh in meshlab e export as .ply the mesh will be with vertex colors